# Assign type to variable - 'A' is a type but is used like a 'variable'?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to dynamically create object based on an input string. And the string to Class type mapping is pre-built in `_l`.

```
class A {....}
class B {....}
var _l = new Dictionary<string, Type> { { "1", A } .... } // Error
// 'A' is a type but is used like a 'variable'

PropertyInfo propertyInfo = _l["0"].GetProperty("xxxx");
ObjectType instance = (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType)
propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, 
    Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

However, I got the error of

> 'A' is a type but is used like a 'variable'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `typeof(A)`

```
var _l = new Dictionary<string, Type> { { "1", typeof(A) } };
```

Comment: A itself is a class not a type. You  need a Type instance.

Comment: Are 'int', 'string' types? For `A aaa = new A()`, we usually say `aaa` has type of 'A'?

Comment: Yes, you can't pass `A` as a parameter to anything because it is an identifier, not an instance, `typeof` generates an instance of `Type`.  Just like an **instance** of `PropertyInfo` is a way to represent a property, `Type` represents a class or other type.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 That terminology is correct, but saying `aaa` is of type `A` is speaking conceptually.  When you see `<string, Type>` we are no longer speaking of a conceptual type, but instead of a specific framework instance called `Type`. You are expected to construct an instance of the `Type` class.

Comment: @AaronLS Can I see type can only be passed as parameter directly when doing generic? Otherwise it need `typeof()`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Are you asking why you don't need a typeof to do this? `Dictionary<string, Type>` That's because it is a declaration, it is the same as the `int` part of `int someVariable` where you are declaring that it is of type `int`.  Where as `{ "1", typeof(A) }` is a list initializer for an instance of KeyValuePair which expects you pass value and/or instances to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var _l = new Dictionary<string, Type> { { "1", typeof(A) } .... }
```

instead